# My Apps SQL Connection doesn't work on iOS but on MacOS windows android and in unity editor

Tags: c#, ios, sql-server, xcode, unity-game-engine

Hope somebody can help me I'm getting frustrated.
A Friend and I are working on an Barcode Scanner App which should connect to a local MS SQL Server and everything is doing great so far, except for the iOS part.

like in the title said everything is working on android etc. but now we tried to use it on an iPhone 7 and the App is crashing as soon as we press our connect Button.

Our Error Code in XCode is:
[image]

By the way we're completely new to everything with SQL

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;

public class SQLConnector : MonoBehaviour {

public Text fail;
SqlConnection connection;


public void OpenSqlConnection()
{

string connectionString = "data source=MyIP,Port;Initial 
Catalog=DataBase;persist security info=false;Integrated Security=false;user  id=myUsername;password=myPassword;";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            connection.Open();

            if (connection != null)
            {

                fail.text = "läuft endlich";
                Debug.Log("läuft");
            }
            else
            {

                Debug.Log("Mist");
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your app directly connected to a SQL database? If so, I'd suggest stopping immediately with what you're doing, and switch over to a REST API. Also, could you post some code on how the connection is established?

Comment: Please include the code, not pictures of the code.